# If two people wanted to play, would each have to buy the cards?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu-lcg

Would there be enough cards for two players to build adequate decks with only one copy of the base set and/or the Asylum Packs, or would each player have to have their own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely, for a reasonable expectation of "adequate". While there aren't enough cards included to create single-faction decks, you could easily make several, viable, multi-faction decks out of nothing but the base set. When you add in a couple of asylum packs, you're set for quite some time.

Comment: Thanks!  Does the same hold true for the Asylum packs?  Can two people make use of a single Asylum Pack?

Comment: @Teryx, yes, if you have the base game they can both use cards from an asylum packs to flesh out their respective factions, unless both have the same factions there are enough cards for some variation. Most (if not all) Asylum Packs include some cards for all available factions, with the exception of the Order of the Silver Twilight, since they were added in an expansion after most of the current asylum packs were released (their expansion pack contains a much larger amounts of their cards to compensate, as do their line of recent asylum packs.).

Answer (score 3):

[This review of the core set](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/375908/the-core-set) says you get about three starter decks worth of cards in the base pack. Plus, the core set is intended to get two people playing.

It looks like you can play two player games of the CoC LCG with only a single copy of the base set.